# Orientation of spin operators in Heisenberg model

Tags: quantum-spin, spin-models

What is meant by orientation of a spin operator (in, for example, Heisenberg model in condensed matter physics)?

For example, in Ising model we have Hamiltonian $H=\displaystyle\sum_{i,j}J_{ij}S_{i}S_{j}$, where we can imagine orientation of spin $S_i$ as spin up ($\uparrow$) or spin down ($\downarrow$) (for example, spin up and down relative to z-axis).

Now, in Heisenberg model $H=\displaystyle\sum_{i,j}J_{ij}\mathbf{S_{i}}\cdot\mathbf{S_{j}}$ we can treat spin $\mathbf{S_i}$ as spin operator (I hope I didn't make a mistake here). In this case, where spins are operators, what would be their orientation in space (for example, relative to each other (parallel or antiparallel orientation) or relative to z-axis)? Is it a projection $m$ of spin $\mathbf{S_i}$ (for example, spin $\mathbf{S_i}$ has spin $S_i$ and its projection is $m=-S_{i},-S_{i}+1,...,S_i$)) or is it something else?

I hope I was clear enough!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about the direction of the spins in the ground state of the model?

Comment: Yes, direction in the ground state.